# OutlinedTextField Autofocus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So I have a compose layout let suppose A which has a text and a see more option. When clicking on it it should navigate to another compose where you can see the remaining text.

So there is edit option also and when trying to edit, I want the focus to be at the end of the text.

How to achieve that.

Below is the code which I am currently working on:

```
OutlinedTextField(
value = textFieldValue,
modifier = modifier,
onValueChange = {
    textFieldValueState = it
    if (value != it.text) {
        onValueChange(it.text)
    }
},
placeholder = placeholder,)
```

Below is the edit screen:

[image]

Comment: This question exhibits lack of research. One single query on cursor positioning in Android gives you the official docs in the top results as the answer. This seems a bit of an excuse to not having to read the docs, and get everything on a platter. Please always do at least a quick web search to see if the issue is resolvable just like that. Other than that, you could just have presser `Ctrl` + `P` in Studio to see all the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selection parameter in the [`TextFieldValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextFieldValue#TextFieldValue(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRange,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRange)) class:

> `selection` - the selection range. If the selection is collapsed, it represents cursor location. When selection range is out of bounds, it is constrained with the text length.

Something like:

```
val content = "content"
var text by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(content, TextRange(content.length)))
}

val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    label = { Text("Label") },
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
)
```

To give the focus you can use:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
     requester.requestFocus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To place the cursor at the end of the text, you must use `TextFieldValue`

The following code, give the focus to the TextField and place the cursor at the end of the text :

```
@Composable
fun TestTextField(title: String = "Hello") {
    val titleFocusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val titleTextFieldValueState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(
                text = title,
                selection = TextRange(title.length)
            )
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        titleFocusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .focusRequester(titleFocusRequester),
            value = titleTextFieldValueState.value,
            onValueChange = { tfv: TextFieldValue ->
                titleTextFieldValueState.value = tfv
            }
        )
    }
}
```